# Is there always a multiple of $a$, such that $an \mod p = 1$ if $p$ is prime?

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I'm working on a proof which I know can be achieved if the following is true:

For every prime number $p$, and every whole number $x,x<p$ it is true that there exists some whole $n$ such that $nx\mod p = 1$

If I try it for small primes I see it holds, but I have trouble arriving at a general proof. Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1):

Fix $x$ integer not multiple of $p$. Consider the function $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ given by $a\mapsto ax$. If we prove that this function is surjective, we have in particular $a\in\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ such that $ax\equiv 1\pmod p$. Since the domain and the codomain are both finite sets with the same cardinality, it is equivalent to prove that such function is injective. Now suppose that $ax\equiv bx\pmod p$ for some $a,b$. Then $p\mid x(a-b)$, but $p$ does not divide $x$ so $p\mid a-b$, that is $a\equiv b\pmod p$, so the function is in fact injective.